# Can't save edited docx file loaded in MemoryStream

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, memorystream

I have a **WebAPI** in **C#**, and I need to load a Document by POST, modify some parameters, and save it to an Azure Blob account.

I can read the file, I can modify the parameters, but when I save it to Azure, the document is saved as the original file.

```
/* file es del tipo System.Net.Http.StreamContent que viene en un POST */

byte[] byteArray = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
MemoryStream docStream = new MemoryStream();

docStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
docStream.Seek(0x00000000, SeekOrigin.Begin);

WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docStream, true);
MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

var descedants = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>();

var idRef = descedants.Where(c => c.FirstChild.Elements<SdtAlias>().Where(v => v.Val == "Asunto").Count() > 0).FirstOrDefault();
if (idRef != null && user != null)
{
    var tNomRef = idRef.Elements<SdtContentRun>().FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault();
    var textNomRef = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlLeafTextElement)tNomRef.LastOrDefault();
    textNomRef.Text = info.idDocumento;
}

var titRef = descedants.Where(c => c.FirstChild.Elements<SdtAlias>().Where(v => v.Val == "Título").Count() > 0).FirstOrDefault();
if (titRef != null && user != null)
{
    var tNomRef = idRef.Elements<SdtContentRun>().FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault();
    var textNomRef = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlLeafTextElement)tNomRef.LastOrDefault();
    textNomRef.Text = info.nomDocumento;
}

/* Este objeto se encarga de subir el archivo a un Blob Storage de Azure */
CloudBlockBlob blob = imagesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(xNombre);
docStream.Position = 0;
blob.UploadFromStream(docStream);
docStream.Close();
docStream.Dispose();
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: OK, thanks for your time and explanations. I will do this in the future. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the doc(WordprocessingDocument) has been modified, you need to save the changes back to docStream(MemoryStream) before uploading the docStream to blob storage. What you need do is just adding doc.Save() before uploading the docStream. Code below is for your reference.

```
doc.Save();

CloudBlockBlob blob = imagesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(xNombre);
docStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. I add this to my code, and finally it works.

Comment: doc.Save();
    byte[] newArray = docStream.ToArray();
    
    blob.UploadFromByteArray(newArray, 0, newArray.Length);

Answer (score 1):

You're populating a DOM structure from the stream.

Unless you actually save it back somewhere, the original stream is not affected.

You should create a new stream and save the edited document to it.

Comment: Hi SLaks, thanks for your response, but how I can do it? I try creating a new MemoryStream, but when I save the documento into this, the MemoryStream closes, and I can´t read it or upload it to Azure.

Comment: @JuanRíos: Use `ToArray()`.

Comment: I think I don't understand, if I convert the actual MemoryStream to Byte Array, the file is the same. What thing will I be leaving out?